# Break a string into triples (tuple of three fields),of subject predicate and object .

Tags: python, algorithm, rdf

E.g :

Sample RDF string .

<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "In_the_Bedroom" , "The_Patriot_(2000_film)" , "Black_Knight_(film)" , "The_Last_Kiss" , "Cassandras_Dream";   <bornOnDate> "1948-12-12"; <isCalled> "Tom Wilkinson (Schauspieler)" , "טום וילקינסון" , "トム・ウィルキンソン" , "Tom Wilkinson" , "ום וילקינסון" , "ム・ウィルキンソン";  .

Triples for given string -

```
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "In_the_Bedroom"     
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "The_Patriot_(2000_film)" 
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "Black_Knight_(film)" 
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "The_Last_Kiss" 
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "Cassandras_Dream"
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <bornOnDate> "1948-12-12"
<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <isCalled> "Tom Wilkinson (Schauspieler)"
```

Note - There can be spaces in between objects. For say "Tom Wilkinson (Schauspieler)" is an object containing spaces in between.

Answer (score 5):

The input you're giving is actually the Turtle (or N3) serialization of some RDF already.  It would typically be formatted something like this, with some `@base` specified:

```
@base <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/1281433> .

<Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <actedIn> "In_the_Bedroom" , "The_Patriot_(2000_film)" ,
                                  "Black_Knight_(film)" , "The_Last_Kiss" ,
                                  "Cassandras_Dream";
                        <bornOnDate> "1948-12-12";
                        <isCalled> "Tom Wilkinson (Schauspieler)" ,
                                   "טום וילקינסון" , "トム・ウィルキンソン" ,
                                   "Tom Wilkinson" , "ום וילקינסון" ,
                                   "ム・ウィルキンソン" .
```

If you add the appropriate `@base` declaration, then you can use any library that can read Turtle and serialize in N-Triples to read the input and write the output.  For instance, using Jena's [`rdfcat`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/jena/rdfcat.html) you can convert to a number of different formats, including N-Triples:

```
$ rdfcat -out N-TRIPLES input.ttl
```

```
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/actedIn> "Black_Knight_(film)" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "ム・ウィルキンソン" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "トム・ウィルキンソン" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "Tom Wilkinson (Schauspieler)" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "ום וילקינסון" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "טום וילקינסון" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/actedIn> "The_Last_Kiss" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/bornOnDate> "1948-12-12" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/actedIn> "The_Patriot_(2000_film)" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/actedIn> "In_the_Bedroom" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/isCalled> "Tom Wilkinson" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/Tom_Wilkinson_(actor)> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192184/actedIn> "Cassandras_Dream" .
```

Since you tagged this with Python, you might find [RDFlib](https://github.com/RDFLib) more useful than Jena, but the real question here should be about how to do the conversion, not the library request (since library requests are off topic for Stack Overflow).

Answer (score -2):

Try using [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib).
Looks like they have [examples on parsing ntriples](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_parsing.html)

EDIT: the format is actually `n3`. See [these docs](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph.parse) on `parse()`

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code on how to use that library for above given format .Or atleast you can hint me about what does that format called.

Comment: THe input isn't N-Triples, but N3/Turtle.